# adding datime.datetime and datetime.time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I am trying to add datetime.datetime and datetime.time to get one column. I was trying combine:

```
import datetime as dt
dt.datetime.combine(myDF['Date'].astype(dt.date), myDF['Time'].astype(dt.time))
```

but I get:

```
TypeError: combine() argument 1 must be datetime.date, not Series
```

and I was trying this:

```
myDF['Date'] + myDF['Time']
```

but I get

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.time'
```

does anybody know, how I can combine my two colums?

```
             Date               Time
0    2011-08-08 00:00:00      08:10:00
1    2011-08-08 00:00:00      08:10:00
2    2011-08-08 00:00:00      08:10:00
3    2011-08-08 00:00:00      11:20:00
4    2011-08-08 00:00:00      12:25:00
5    2011-08-08 00:00:00      14:20:00
```

Comment: Some of your example doesn't quite make sense.  I think you need to show your imports.

Comment: oh, sorry. I import datetime as dt. do you mean that?

Comment: Yeah, that makes more sense now.

Comment: Why the `astype()` calls? Your `+` error shows you already have `datetime.datetime` and `datetime.time` objects in your rows.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that all the rows have the same format. There are more than those I show here. You are right. I might not even need that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to combine *whole columns*, but `datetime.combine()` doesn't know how to be applied to separate columns.

Use the [`DataFrame.apply()` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) instead:

```
def combine_cols(row):
    return dt.datetime.combine(
        row['Date'].date(), row['Time'])

myDF.apply(combine_cols, axis=1)
```

`axis=1` tells `apply()` to pass each row to the callable.

Demo:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> myDF = pd.DataFrame({
...     'Date': pd.Series([dt.datetime(2011, 8, 8)] * 6),
...     'Time': pd.Series([dt.time(8, 10), dt.time(8, 10), dt.time(8, 10), dt.time(11, 20), dt.time(12, 25), dt.time(14, 20)])
... })
>>> myDF
        Date      Time
0 2011-08-08  08:10:00
1 2011-08-08  08:10:00
2 2011-08-08  08:10:00
3 2011-08-08  11:20:00
4 2011-08-08  12:25:00
5 2011-08-08  14:20:00
>>> def combine_cols(row):
...     return dt.datetime.combine(
...         row['Date'].date(), row['Time'])
...
>>> myDF.apply(combine_cols, axis=1)
0   2011-08-08 08:10:00
1   2011-08-08 08:10:00
2   2011-08-08 08:10:00
3   2011-08-08 11:20:00
4   2011-08-08 12:25:00
5   2011-08-08 14:20:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```